# Помогите с задачей по сортировке

Tags: c#

Не могу найти ошибку в прграмме. Мне нужно чтоб пользователь вводил массив, а на выход программа выдавала уже отсортированный массив в порядке убывания. Программа выдает ошибку после ввода элементов. Вот мой код: `

```
        int f, k;

        Console.WriteLine("Введите разменость массива: ");
        k = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());

        Console.WriteLine("Вводите элементы массива: ");

        int[] mass = new int[k];
        for (int i = 0; i < mass.Length; i++)
        {
            mass[i] = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < mass.Length; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < mass.Length - 1; j++)
            {
                f = mass[i];
                mass[i] = mass[i + 1];
                mass[i + 1] = f;
            }
        }

        Console.WriteLine(mass);
        Console.ReadKey();`
```

Comment: `int f, k;` старайтесь объявлять переменные при первом использовании, а не заранее. Так код легче будет читать.

Answer (score 3):

```
mass[i + 1]
```

Здесь вы выходите за границу массива на последней итерации по `i`, когда `i = mass.Length - 1`.

Вы никак не используете переменную `j`, по которой у вас есть цикл.

Кроме того, для сортировки вы должны сравнивать элементы, а не обменивать их местами всегда. Подумайте ещё над алгоритмом. Без сравнения сортировка невозможна.